# nginx-1.19.8 - нет исполняемого файла

Tags: nginx

Пропал в этой версии nginx.exe ).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как запустить?

Comment: Эм, кажется это исходный код. Откуда вы его скачали?

Comment: https://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.19.8.zip вот нормальный дистр

Comment: Спасибо Алексей )